# baffling regex issue in Exchange

Tags: exchange, regex

I have a transport rule in Exchange 2010 which is not behaving itself, and I get berated by the EMC if I try to fix it.

The objective of the rule is block any email coming from a domain with "us" at the end of the address, except if it comes from a domain which ends in a legitimate US state abbreviation, such as NY.US or CA.US

As written, the pattern matches are:

`.*@.*.us$` (any email ending in ".us")

except

`.*@.*.az.us$` (state abbreviations)

The . (period) metacharacter seems to be the culprit here, but if I try to escape it with a backslash, as in:

`.*@.*\.us$` (any email ending in ".us")

except

`.*@.*\.az.us$` (state abbreviations)

the EMC complains "The regular expression you entered contains the following error. There's a problem with your use of the backslash character. In a regular expression, the backslash character is used for text pattern matching... The backslash character can also be used as an escape character ..."

which is exactly what I am trying to do.

Any idea of how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're using the backslash incorrectly.  I'm not sure why you're trying to escape one of those periods, [but that's not proper syntax, and that's why the EMC is telling you there's a problem with your use of the backslash character](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997187%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> A backslash is used as an escaping character before a special character. Special characters are characters used in pattern strings:
>
> Backslash ( \ )
>
> Pipe ( | )
>
> Asterisk ( * )
>
> Opening parenthesis ( ( )
>
> Closing parenthesis ( ) )
>
> Caret ( ^ )
>
> Dollar sign ( $ )
>
> For example, if you want to match a string that contains (525), you would type (525).

In other words, you can't use a backslash to "escape" a period.